# Tinymce close on drag when zoominfo extension enabled

Tags: jquery, reactjs, tinymce, zoom-sdk

I installed Zoominfo extension and enabled
when i using TinyMce toolbar ondrag, toolbar getting close.

I try no-conflict mode in jquer.

i want tinyMCE toolbar to drag when extension enabled,

looks like that extension also using .ui-draggable class for drag element

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.